# How can I get Firefox to open a cached version of a page in new tabs?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs, browser-cache, homepage

At work, we use a bug-tracking system to keep track of what work needs to be done. I can set the new tab page to be a list of all of my bugs, however this page loads slowly, as the site queries a database to get the list.

I would like Firefox to open a cached version of this page every time I open a new tab, so that it loads faster. If I wanted an up-to-date version of the page, ideally I would just be able to click refresh. Does this functionality exist, either in Firefox itself or in an add-on?

I tried changing the `browser.newtab.preload` value in about:config to true, but this does something very different from what I want. It simply opens a blank page first then swaps in the home page once it's done loading. I want to see the webpage instantly.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not intranet web page then you can use something called https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/cachemachine/

You can use tab addons like tabmixer to activate the extension on opening the tab.

Comment: That is cool. Unfortunately in my case it is an internal site :/

Comment: Microsoft has some intresting way to keep a cache copy . Check it out http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196646